# How to change primary key type in postgreSQL to bigserial using Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, primary-key

How can I change the type of the primary key column of an existing table from `serial` (int) to `bigserial` (bigint) in postgres?

The database is used by a Rails App. Do I need to make any changes to the app?

Comment: I think I should have asked this in DB Administrators Exchange

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a migration:

```
bundle exec rails generate migration ChangeSerialToBigserial
```

Edit migration file:

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE bigint"
end
```

Login to the `rails dbconsole`(it is just `psql` console only with chosen a database for your app):

```
bundle exec rails dbconsole
```

Check table:

```
# \d my_table
                                           Table "public.my_table"
         Column         |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | bigint                      | not null default nextval('my_table_id_seq'::regclass)
```

The same `sql` query like in a migration file you can run directly from `psql`:

```
my_database=# ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE bigint;
```

As [`@Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951585/how-to-change-primary-key-type-in-postgresql-to-bigserial#comment48025899_29951892) suggest **Any column that references my_table.id will have to be changed, too.** Thats mean if you have the `Post` model with `my_table_id` it should be changed too.

Comment: Any column that references my_table.id will have to be changed, too.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' thanks for this point, i am not a database administrator. =).

Answer (score 11):

I believe the accepted answer is only half the story. You must also modify your sequence.

In particular, after only change the type of the id column, you still have:

```
# \d my_table_id_seq
                   Sequence "public.my_table_id_seq"
  Type   | Start | Minimum |  Maximum   | Increment | Cycles? | Cache
---------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+-------
 integer |     1 |       1 | 2147483647 |         1 | no      |     1
```

You then need to run `alter sequence mytable_id_seq as bigint;`

The result is:

```
# \d my_table_id_seq
                       Sequence "public.my_table_id_seq"
  Type  | Start | Minimum |       Maximum       | Increment | Cycles? | Cache
--------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------+-------
 bigint |     1 |       1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 | no      |     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ConvertIntToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    query = <<-SQL
      SELECT tablename AS "tablename"
      FROM pg_tables
      WHERE schemaname = 'public';
    SQL
    connection.execute(query).each do |element|
      if column_exists?(element['tablename'], :id, :integer)
        change_table(element['tablename']) {|t| t.change :id, :bigint }
      end
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanded version of @I0Result's answer, this also changes sequences and (most) foreign keys:

```
class ConvertIntToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    query = <<-SQL
      SELECT tablename AS "tablename"
      FROM pg_tables
      WHERE schemaname = 'public';
    SQL
    tablenames = connection.execute(query).map { |r| r['tablename'] }
    tablenames.each do |tablename|
      next if ["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata"].include?(tablename)
      # change any "id" columns and their sequences to bigint
      if column_exists?(tablename, :id, :integer)
        change_table(tablename) { |t| t.change :id, :bigint }
        connection.execute("alter sequence #{tablename}_id_seq as bigint")
      end
      # try to find any associations that use a foreign key and change that to bigint, too
      model = begin
        tablename.classify.constantize
      rescue StandardError => e # join tables have no model
        nil
      end
      if model and model.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        model.reflect_on_all_associations.each do |assoc|
          foreign_key_name = assoc.foreign_key
          if column_exists?(tablename, foreign_key_name, :integer)
            change_table(tablename) { |t| t.change foreign_key_name, :bigint }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```